# Client Credentials Grant on CRM Dynamics 2016 On Premise Web API

Tags: asp.net-web-api, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

I am trying to call the CRM Dynamics On Premise 2016 Web API.
I configured Authorization Code Flow using OAuth and it is working. But, i need to set up the Client Credentials flow since many applications are running on background and they can't be prompted with login screen.
Since, its On Premise, we dont have Azure AD.

1. Where do we go and register our application?
2. Is there another way to access Web API for On premise dynamics CRM( For example userid,password etc)

Comment: I haven't done it, but you might want to look into an OAuth2 [Password Grant](https://www.oauth.com/oauth2-servers/access-tokens/password-grant/)...

Answer (score 0):

Xrm api is accessible via client credentials without any special setup (be it on-prem or on-line) - you just setup S2S user with appropriate permissions, and you can log him in like:

```
static void InContext(Action<IOrganizationService> callback, Org org)
{
    var credentials = new ClientCredentials();
    if (!org.IsLocal)
    {
        credentials.UserName.UserName = org.UserName;
        credentials.UserName.Password = org.Password;
    }
    else
    {
        credentials.Windows.ClientCredential = new NetworkCredential(org.UserName, org.Password);
    }

    using (var serviceProxy =
                new OrganizationServiceProxy(new Uri(org.OrganizationServiceUri),
                    null, credentials
                    , null))
    {
            callback.Invoke(serviceProxy);
    }
}

public class Org
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string OrganizationServiceUri { get; set; }
    public bool IsLocal { get; set; }

    public Org()
    {
    }

    public Org(bool isLocal, string userName, string password, string organizationServiceUri)
    {
        IsLocal = isLocal;
        UserName = userName;
        Password = password;
        OrganizationServiceUri = organizationServiceUri;
        DiscoveryServiceUri = discoveryServiceUri;
    }
}
```

And then in your backend code:

```
var org = new Org(true, "Administrator", "Password", 
  "http://ondracrm/org/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc");

 InContext((os) => {
   // some sample work with organization service
   var response = (RetrieveEntityResponse)os.Execute(
      new RetrieveEntityRequest 
      { 
        LogicalName = "contact", 
        EntityFilters = EntityFilters.Attributes 
      });
 }, org);
```